# Excel VBA: Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am new in a Excel Vba, and I'm getting this error when I try to run my macro. So my task is to make a electronic journal.I need to make that every teacher can only see their own marks. My idea was doing that with a password and very hidden function. The error is getting on a marked place in code. Can you help me solving the problem ? Thank you very much!!

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim myPassword1, myPassword2, myPassword3, myPassword4, myPassword5, myPassword6, myPassword7, myPassword8, myPassword9, myPassword10, myPassword11, myPassword12, myPassword13, myPassword14, myPassword15 As String

Srpski = "pas1"
Engleski = "pas2"
Fizicko = "pas3"
Matematika = "pas4"
Informatika = "pas5"
Istorija = "pas6"
Likovno = "pas7"
Hemija = "pas8"
Fizika = "pas9"
Osnove = "pas10"
Multimedija = "pas11"
IKT = "pas12"
Praksa = "pas13"
Izborni = "pas14"
Ostalo = "pas15"

Password = InputBox("Unesite lozinku:")

If Password = "" Then
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Srp").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Eng").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Fizc").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Mat").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Info").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Ist").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Lik").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Hem").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Fiz").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Osn").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Mult").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Ikt").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Prk").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Izb").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Ost").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 Exit Sub

ElseIf Password = Srpski Then
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Srp").Visible = True 'This is the place where error shows
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Eng").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Fizc").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Mat").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Info").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Ist").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Lik").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Hem").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Fiz").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Osn").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Mult").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Ikt").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Prk").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Izb").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Ost").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

....
```

Comment: `Range`s do not have the `Visible` property. `Sheet`s do.

Comment: Yes, so ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Visible = True would fix it.

Comment: Ok, but I have to hide only certain cells in a sheet "1" ? What should I do ?

Comment: You would do best to put the details for each teacher on a different sheet.  (P.S.  Your code is declaring `myPassword15` `As String`, but `myPassword1`, `myPassword2`, etc are being declared `As Variant`.)

Comment: Well then,that will be a lot of work. 13 school objects * 33 students ,for each ,one sheet, that's 495 sheets...

Comment: [Range.Hidden Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx)

Comment: You mention teachers should "only see their own marks" - is it okay it a teacher sees another's marks? I ask because if that's a violation of privacy or some thing, it's not too hard in Excel to see those other marks if you know what you're doing.  Therefore, I think @YowE3K's suggestion may work best, as you can hide the unnecessary worksheets (or perhaps better yet, have a macro copy each teacher's WS into a new book, and only share that book with that teacher.)  That'd be a lot of sheets/workbooks yes, but with VBA shouldn't be a very complicated thing to do.

Comment: Hm... teacher shouldn't see other marks. Only his. Anyway,thank you for replying. I will try something from above.

Comment: What is the process around this electronic journal? Do you intend to send it to each teacher or is it supposed to be some sort of shared spreadsheet edited potentially by more people at once? I suspect it may not be a good idea in the first place to give even password-protected information to people who are not entitled to it if you can avoid it. I would be afraid that somebody makes their range/sheet/whatever your solution is unhidden and the next person will be able to see it. You can't rely on auto_open because people will need to allow macros first...

Comment: My solution would be to have a single workbook on your side (assembling all data) and having macros to a) update it easily if a teacher sends you spreadsheet for their subject; b) to send individual worksheets to the appropriate teachers if they need to inspect it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Honestly, I don't really know what is teacher going to do with it, I think that his going to upload it on some kind of server and every teacher in school will have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider a Dictionary way to shorten and make more flexible your code

- format *all* your `Sheets("1")` "teachers" ranges (i.e.: `Sheets("1").Range("Srp")`, `Sheets("1").Range("Eng")`, ...) as follows

  - character color = white
  - cell format protection: hidden

  this way your sheet always starts off with all matters ranges "hidden", meaning their content is not visible by the user interface
- protect your sheet with any password (let's say "mypwd")

  this, to have your "hiding" formatting effective
- in VBA IDE add the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference

  - click Tools -> References
  - scroll listbox down to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" entry and tick its chekmark
  - click OK
- use this code

  ```
  Sub Makro1()
      Dim Password As String
      Dim passwordsDict As Scripting.Dictionary

      Set passwordsDict = GetPasswords '<--| retrieve all correspondencies of any valid password to its matter

      Password = Application.InputBox("Unesite lozinku:", "Input Password", Type:=2) '<--| retrieve password requiring a text (string) value

      If passwordsDict.Exists(Password) Then '<--| if input password is a valid one...
          With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1") '<--| ...reference
              .Unprotect Password:="mypwd"
              With passwordsDict(Password)
                  .Font.ColorIndex = 1 'make characters font black and see them
                  .FormulaHidden = False ' unhide formula bar cell insight
              End With
              .Protect Password:="mypwd"
          End With
      Else '<--| if input password isn't a valid one
          MsgBox "Sorry!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Invalid password", vbCritical + vbInformation, "Password" '<--| inform the user and exit
      End If
  End Sub

  Function GetPasswords() As Scripting.Dictionary
      Dim myDict As Scripting.Dictionary

      Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary '<--| set a new dictionary
      With myDict
          .Add "pas1", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Srp")
          .Add "pas2", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Eng")
          .Add "pas3", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Fizc")
          .Add "pas4", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Mat")
          .Add "pas5", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("Info")
          '... '<--| add your other password/range correspondency couples
      End With
      Set GetPasswords = myDict '<--| return the passwords/ranges dictionary
  End Function
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, will try that , and see if it works.

Comment: The code works great, but I have one question about it. After inputing the marks ,is there any way that "enabled" marks ,after exit, again become invisible,for the next opening of file. Because, for example, the teacher of math would see what teacher of physics have inputed in journal a school class ago.

Comment: you can use a `Workbook_Open()` event handler placed in `ThisWorkbook` code pane where you always hide all ranges at opening workbook